# loss function for supervised anomaly detection in time series

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, unbalanced-classes, supervised-learning, anomaly-detection

I have a supervised anomaly detection problem in a time series data, which the dataset has three columns:

- datetime
- value(a float number)
- label(1 for anomaly, 0 for normal)

It's common that the labels are imbalanced and anomalies are much fewer than normal samples.

According to explanations said above, how can I predict labels(0/1 outputs) for the test data? What appropriate loss function can I define for it?